# divide operator error in PostgreSql: operator does not exist: unknown /

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `Trip` table in PostgreSQL DB, there is a column called `meta` in the table.

A example of `meta` in one row looks like:

```
meta = {"runTime": 3922000, "distance": 85132, "duration": 4049000, "fuelUsed": 19.595927498516176}
```

To select the trip which has largest value divided by "distance" and "runTime", I run query:

```
select MAX(tp."meta"->>'distance'/tp."meta"->>'runTime') maxkph FROM "Trip" tp
```

but I get ERROR:

```
/* ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown / jsonb LINE 1: MAX(tp."meta"->>'distance'/tp."meta"...
```

I also tried:

```
select MAX((tp."meta"->>'distance')/(tp."meta"->>'runTime')) maxkph FROM "Trip" tp
```

but get another ERROR:

```
/* ERROR:  operator does not exist: text / text LINE 1: ...MAX((tp."meta"->>'distance')/(tp."meta...
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using parentheses:

```
MAX( (tp."meta"->>'distance') / (tp."meta"->>'runTime') ) as maxkph
```

Your second problem suggests that these values are stored as strings.  So convert them:

```
MAX( (tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric / (tp."meta"->>'runTime')::numeric ) as maxkph
```

Comment: Many thanks for check my question. I have tried your method, but get another error. I have modified my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is not operator `div` for jsonb values. You have to cast a values on both sizes to some numeric type first:

```
MAX( ((tp."meta"->>'distance')::numeric) / ((tp."meta"->>'runTime')::numeric) ) maxkph
```